# Are there any links to forms that can be printed and filled by non-citizens entering India?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, india

Are there any links to forms that can be printed and filled by non-citizens entering India?

And would these printed forms be accepted by the Immigration officials?

Comment: If I remember correctly foreigners fill out an Immigration arrival card, and Indians a departure card, whereas there's a Customs declaration to be filled out by everyone on arrival. I can't imagine the authorities will let you print out your own. The forms are distributed on the plane.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. Were you asking about eVisa for entering India?

Comment: It is a form that is submitted on arrival to the immigration officials.  Not eVisa.  Use of QR codes has become quite pervasive in India. I thought may be paper arrival form is replaced by electronic form.  Sadly not.